# How to filter with manytomany field?

Tags: django, django-models

I have model":

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, blank = True, null=True)
```

and i want to filter (site is a correct Site object):

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(field1=thing, sites__id=site.id)
```

but this doesn't work. I get all objects, even those who do not have an entry in the table.

or i tried:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(field1=thing, sites__in=site)
```

but i get nothing. Ho to do it?

Comment: I think that sites__in needs a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand your question right you have a specific `site` and your trying to `filter` by that site. Then you should filter like this:

```
site = Site.objects.get(pk=1)

mymodel_for_site = MyModel.objects.filter(field1=thing, sites=site)
```

This should get all the MyModel instances for a particular `site`

Answer (score -1):

Try to make it via MyModel object, i.e.:

```
object = MyModel.objects.get(field1=thing)
qs = object.sites.all()
```

Check django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: I have many objects and i must use filter instead get. I want to get objects assigned to specific site.

Comment: that will give all the `sites` it will not filter based on a particular `site`